# Does Twitter track a tweets originating IP Address?

Tags: ipad, twitter

I had an iPad stolen a few months ago. A few days ago, the thief accidentally tweeted a random photo. That iPad has location services and iCloud disabled, so that's out. But, it brings me to the question at hand...

Does Twitter track the originating IP address for each tweet? If so, is there any immediate way to get it? I don't see it in any API documentation.

Here is all the data I can muster about said tweet: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/215632207346270209.json

Comment: how do you know that guy twit a photo?

Comment: Have you contacted Twitter and described the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They sure do, but you will have to obtain a court order for them to hand it over to you. Plus you will need a court order to get the user details from the ISP